# What happens to a terrestrial body bound to a far away galaxy?

Tags: energy-conservation, space-expansion, observable-universe

Suppose that I could find an imaginary rope long enough to bind myself to a very distant planet, i.e. a planet within a very far away galaxy so that it is moving with the Hubble flow. To keep things simpler, the rope is not only very long but also of infinite strength. And also let choose a galaxy within the observable universe, at least to begin with.

1 - Will the expansion lift me off? 
I would say yes, but perhaps I am wrong. If I do NOT start flying up, it is like that I displace the planet, and through gravity there, the entire galaxy from its comoving coordinate.

2 - if answer to 1 is YES, what is then the situation when my rope connects two comparable planets, one "here" and one in that far away galaxy?

Note that I choose planets as anchoring points instead of galaxies or stars so the rope won't burn ;)

ADDENDUM: I wanted to started in a way easy to me, but I've just realised that, within my thinking, probably the question is just as in 2), as for I am bound to the milky way. So what happens to two far apart galaxies connected to each other? Or alternatively what happens to the rope between them? There will be a tension, I suppose. What is happening if its limits are reached and it breaks?

If the question is too picturesque, consider two masses m1 and m2, still far away but within the observable universe. Case1) is m1 <<< m2, and case 2) is m1 = m2.

An answer addressing, even briefly, both points 1) & 2) is still welcomed as it will certainly contribute to my comprehension. Thanks.

Comment: Just a reminder, galaxies are not flying away from each other, the spacetime itself is expanding. That means everything in it is also moving away from each other. Your rope would seem expanding too(even if it is of infinite strength).

Comment: @Ari. Are you sure that the rope will expand? It seems against the fact that we, Earth, Milky Way etc are not expanding with the Hubble flow. If it is so I must rethink (which I am always doing, by the way :) all the very little I know in cosmology.

Comment: @Ari that is not correct. Bound objects do not expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me start with another thought experiment to get a feeling for these very long distances.

Consider yourself on Earth holding a stick reaching to the surface of the Sun, but not touching it. If you now would push that stick, it would take approximately a little bit more than 8 minutes till the stick touches the Sun. Why 8 minutes? Because that's the time light (or information) needs to travel from the Sun to Earth. So when you push that rigid stick, the information about that push (compressing and expanding the various distances between the atomic layers within the stick) can not travel faster than the speed of light.

Now when you expand that stick or rope to the nearest galaxy (Canis Major Dwarf - 25,000 light years) or the more popular Andromeda Galaxy (~220,000 light years), you get a feeling how long 'interactions' will take to reach you, if a planet whtin this galaxy 'pulls' on that rope.

---

To answer your 1st question, you have to consider that space is expanding. So considering a rope, which obviously 'occupies' part of the expanding space. And here it gets a little bit complicated, since the intrinsic expansion of space is not a force, but a change of the scale of space itself. But when an object, like the rope, should not follow that expansion i.e., it should not be torn apart, a force has to act against this expansion. Also, a rope with 'infinite strength' can not (by definition) burst, so it will pull you towards that planet. But this 'pull' towards that planet will be very very slowly.

At first it will take about 25,000 years until you 'feel' the pull of that planet. Then, if you assume that the Earth and the other planet are not orbiting a star or galaxy, you will be pulled with the a velocity of $H_0d$ ($H_0 \approx 70\text{km/s/MPc}$ is the Hubble constant and $d$ the length of the rope or distance to the planet) towards the planet. This gives about $70\cdot 0.00766 = 0.5\text{km/s}$ towards Canis Major Dwarf.

You will not displace the planet, because the force you would act on a planet, which is in a bound orbit around a star, is negligible. Consider if you throw a marble (you) against a bowling ball (the planet) - will the bowling ball move? Certainly not, according to Newton's second and third law.

---

2) This is a much more complicated, since the planets have to orbit the stars to not fall into them. They may both 'pull' the rope at the same time, but since information travels the with speed of light, the middle of the rope will feel this pull thousands of years later. Also I don't know what the rope will do, because if you pull at both ends and displace them by 10m, either the rope bursts, or it will expand and contract like a spring and thousand years later both planets will know.

---

Since galaxies are not rigid bodies like (rocky) planets, you can not easily connect or influence them. But when the rope bursts, according to Newton's first law, they will move on with the same velocity as they had when the rope stopped acting a force on them.

Comment: Thanks. All details you add I am and I was aware of. I wrote the question as the story that came to my mind, ie can I travel if I bound myself to... etc etc. Perhaps I should have have just ask about masses m1 and m2. By the way if the stick is ideally rigid there is not delay. I know is tricky to ideate thought experiment, but this seems "reasonable" although unfeasible. I wait to accept your answer. However I upvoted it as you provide a clear yes to point 1), so I will be lift (whatever slow or at the far galaxy rec. Speed, delayed or not).

Comment: Given that my question attracted only your attention, I skip the one supposed to follow-up in case the answer was" yes, you lift off".  I just comment here perhaps you will read it. Now, as the Hubble Flow is not kinetic, as things moving maintain their comoving position, what is doing work on me? Why there is a force on me at I aquire kinetic energy? Is dark energy? But expansion itself doesn't require to be accelerate, so even in Lambda = 0 scenario I will lift. Where the energy comes from?